# Tap button again to confirm action

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, android-button

How to make a button which when pressed would show a toast message asking the user to tap button again to confirm the action. Here is what I have so far,

```
    Button myExitClose = alertLayout.findViewById(R.id.homeExitClose);
    ImageView myExitDismiss = alertLayout.findViewById(R.id.homeExitDismiss);
    final LinearLayout adContainer = alertLayout.findViewById(R.id.homeExitAdView);


    myExitClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            exitDialog.dismiss();
            finish();
        }
    });

    myExitDismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            exitDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alert.setView(alertLayout);
    alert.setCancelable(false);
    exitDialog = alert.create();
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem or result of your code?

Comment: just make new window with button on it and open it onClick ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the button is pressed, record the timestamp of the press. If the button is pressed again, compare the new timestamp to the old one, and perform the special action if the two presses happend close enough together.

```
private Long lastPressedTime = null;
```

```
button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (lastPressedTime == null || (currentTime - lastPressedTime) > 2000) {
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Tap again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        lastPressedTime = currentTime;
    } else {
        finish();
    }
});
```

You can change the `2000` to any number you want; 2000 millis is two seconds, but maybe you want a longer window.

Answer (score 0):

Use handler to schedule for setting button action like this:

```
final OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this,"press back one more time to exit",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            myExitClose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                YourActivity.this.finish();
            });
            new Handler().postDelay(new Runable(){
               myExitClose.setOnClickListener(listener);
            },2000); //wait 2 second for the next pressed
        }
}
myExitClose.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Comment: Thank you for your insight, your code helped me understand my problem better.

Comment: @Imkong Akum Longchar If my answer solves your problem, please accept it, if it does'nt, tell me and i wwill edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Example of how to exit app on double back press within a defined interval:

```
private long backPressed;
private static final int TIME_INTERVAL = 2000;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if( backPressed + TIME_INTERVAL > System.currentTimeMillis() ) {
        finish();
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Tap again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    backPressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Paste code to a listener for an `onClick()`.

Answer (score -1):

This is the basic gist of it. Toast.maketext takes a context, string and a duration.

```
myExitClose.setOnClickListener( (click) ->  {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "StringRes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    });
```

You could also make a Toast object and manipulate placement etc before you show it.

Comment: what will happened next when i press the button one more time??

Comment: The question was just how to make a Toast. Just implement a counter of clicks for the confirmation. Very arbitrary.